# HMAC for kong API

Tags: api, curl, hmac, kong

please...

I need some help with configuration and usage of HMAC for KONG API.

I was following manual published at https://getkong.org/plugins/hmac-authentication/   with demo credentials bob/secret456

The issue is with usage of HMAC auth. I am still getting 403 error - forbiden.

here is my command line output:

```
root@test.com# curl -v http://X:8000/public4/ -H 'Authorization: hmac username="bob", algorithm="hmac-sha1", headers="Date content-md5", signature="Base64(HMAC-SHA1(secret456))"'
> GET /public4/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: XXX:8000
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: hmac username="bob", algorithm="hmac-sha1", headers="X-Date content-md5", signature="Base64(HMAC-SHA1(secret456))" <<- IS THIS CORRECT?
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 13:15:07 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
* Server kong/0.9.7 is not blacklisted
< Server: kong/0.9.7
<
{"message":"HMAC signature cannot be verified, a valid date or x-date header is required for HMAC Authentication"}
* Connection #0 to host XXX left intact
```

Kong consumer:

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "consumer_id": "e98e1ca2-2f13-4430-a658-cabdd4e6cd26",
      "created_at": 1490616124000,
      "username": "bob",
      "id": "037db653-8b38-4a7e-b139-1040856b7cfb",
      "secret": "secret456"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any hint or guideline would be appreciated. Github issues are closed and comments didn't help. I am still getting same error.

Thank you indeed.

Comment: "Base64(HMAC-SHA1(secret456))": You need to compute the hmac and base64 encode it

Answer (score 2):

You are including the string literal "Base64(HMAC-SHA1(secret456))" in your authorization header.  You should be calculating the HMAC of the password, base64 encoding it, and including that value instead.